# Scala scopt code - map getorelse?

Tags: scala, scopt

i am new to scala and do not understand what this code is doing:

```
parser.parse(args, Config()) map {
  config =>
    //do stuff here
} getOrElse {
  //handle stuff here
}
```

This is from the scopt library [found here](https://github.com/scopt/scopt)

Ideally what i want to do is put my code that does all the "do stuff here" into a method that, well, does what I want it to do.

However, when i define my method like so:

```
def setupVariables(config: Option){
    host = config.host
    port = config.port
    delay = config.delay
    outFile = config.outFile

    if (!(new File(config.inputFile)).exists()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("file not found - does the file exist?")
    } else {
      inputFile = config.inputFile
    }
}
```

so that it is called like so:

```
parser.parse(args, Config()) map {
  config =>
    setupVariables(config)
} getOrElse {
  //handle stuff here
}
```

I get the error: `error: class Option takes type parameters
def setupVariables(config: Option){`

My confusion arises because i don't "get" what `parser.parse(args, Config()) map {
      config =>
        //do stuff here
    }` is doing. I can see that parser.parse returns an Option, but what is "map" doing here?

Answer (score 1):

You error occurs because `Option` requires a type parameter, so your `config` argument to `setupVariables` should be an `Option[String]` or an `Option[Config]`.

`Option.map` takes a function `A => B` and uses it to transform an `Option[A]` into an `Option[B]`. You could change your `setupVariables` to have type `Config => Unit` and could do

```
def setupVariables(config: Config) {
    ...
}

parser.parse(args, Config()).map(setupVariables)
```

to create an `Option[Unit]`.

However, since you are only executing `setupVariables` for its effects, I would suggest being more explicit by matching on the result of `parser.parse` e.g.

```
parser.parse(args, Config()) match {
    case Some(cfg): setupVariables(cfg)
    case _ => //parse failed
}
```